# How to map Tables to Java based web applications so as to ease DB migration

Tags: java, jdbc, orm, db2

So, I handle a number of large web applications with each application easily having hundreds of queries.

The tech used is simple - jsp/servlets + business&dao layers in java + jdbc. We are using IBM DB2 as the db.

We are migrating the DB. This will be done batch by batch, meaning only a few tables will be moved at a time. I don't control the decision making on the db side and the whole process is supposed to take over a year.

But, I do face the risk. So, suppose there is a join between table 1 and table 2, and table 1 no longer exists on the old db. Then, queries in one of my applications will fail.

So, is there a tool that will tell me which applications use which tables, so that I can plan to migrate my applications accordingly. Sort of like a crawler, but for Java ?

I know I can write something for this purpose, but if a tool already exists, that would save me a lot of effort.

Answer (score 1):

More than one method exists.

- If each application uses a unique account to connect to the         database,    then the DB2 DBA can record all of the SQL (whether         dynamic or    static) being run by that account. This is trivial when the DB2 server is running on Linux/Unix/Windows, but more politically awkward when the DB2-server runs on AS/400(i-series) or Z-series. With all that SQL you can do your own parsing to find dependencies and relationships.
- If applications share a common-account when connecting to the    database then the DB2 DBA can filter additionally on the IP-address of the application-server, to obtain the SQL that is running from those IP-addresses.
- Depending on the app-server used, and the jdbc-client used, it's also    possible to use a jdbc trace (impacts performance) on the    application-server without involving a DB2 DBA. You would do this on    a non-prod server but you need 100% coverage of the SQL in the tool used to exercise the app.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of JPA or hibernate. It map user classes to tables in the database application, so all you need do is run your applications and all tables are created. In the event of a possible deletion of any table, JPA or hibernate recreates the table immediately using the definitions from the classes mapped to the db.